# Page scrolls back on each post back

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, smooth-scrolling, autopostback

i have successfully completed my web application for an organization and it works up to expectations but i noticed one problem and tried to cure it via searching on Google and asking seniors but none of these helped much.

Problem: I have multiple drop downs lists on page, in which selecting value in one drop down triggers the loading of another drop down i.e. Country > cities situation, problem is that whenever i click any value it scrolls page to the top and i have to scroll back again then again and again which realy looks bad and unprofessional. Please help me.

Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frmReceivedSms.aspx.cs" Inherits="SmsComplaints" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSendSms").hide();
            $("#btnDelete").hide();
            $("#btnCancel").hide();
            $("#lblSelectedID-Span").hide();
            $("#txtSelectedID-Span").hide();
            var showHide = $("#HiddenFieldShowHideButtons").val();
            if (showHide == "True") {
                $("#btnSendSms").show();
                $("#btnDelete").show();
                $("#btnCancel").show();
                $("#lblSelectedID-Span").show();
                $("#txtSelectedID-Span").show();
                $("#buttonSearch").hide();
                $("#Save-Span").hide();
                $("#HiddenFieldShowHideButtons").val("False");
            }
            $("#btnSendSms").click(function () {
                $("#ConfirmMsg").text("Are you sure to update this record?");
                $("#Delete-Span").hide();
                $("#lblSelectedID-Span").hide();
                $("#txtSelectedID-Span").hide();
                $("#Save-Span").show();
                $("#buttonSearch").show();
                $("#Update-Span").show();
                $("#btnSendSms").hide();
                $("#btnDelete").hide();
                $("#btnCancel").hide();
                $("#ModalConfirmAction").modal({ show: true })
            });

            $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
                $("#ConfirmMsg").text("Are you sure to delete this record?");
                $("#Update-Span").hide();
                $("#lblSelectedID-Span").hide();
                $("#txtSelectedID-Span").hide();
                $("#Delete-Span").show();
                $("#Save-Span").show();
                $("#buttonSearch").show();
                $("#btnDelete").hide();
                $("#btnSendSms").hide();
                $("#btnCancel").hide();
                $("#ModalConfirmAction").modal({ show: true })
            });

            $("#btnCancel").click(function () {
                $("#btnSendSms").hide();
                $("#btnDelete").hide();
                $("#btnCancel").hide();
                $("#lblSelectedID-Span").hide();
                $("#txtSelectedID-Span").hide();
                $("#buttonSearch").show();
                $("#Save-Span").show();
                ClearTextBoxes();
            });
        });

        function ClearTextBoxes() {
            $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                $(this).val("");

            });
        }

        function validate() {

            var setValue = false;
            var NotificationSummary = new Array();
            var fields = new Array("Admin Role");
            var txtboxes = new Array($("#txtAdminName"));

            $(txtboxes).each(function (index) {
                if ($(this).val() == "") {
                    NotificationSummary[index] = fields[index];
                    setValue = true;
                }
            });
            if (setValue == true) {
                $("#ConfirmMsg").text = NotificationSummary.join(",");
                $("#ModalConfirmAction").modal({ show: true })
            }
            return setValue;
        }

        $("#Save-Span").click(function () {
            validate();
        });
    </script>


<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<%--<script type="text/javascript">  //Maintain scroll on post back but doesn't load values in relevant drop down
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        xPos = $get('ContentPlaceHolder1').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('ContentPlaceHolder1').scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('ContentPlaceHolder1').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('ContentPlaceHolder1').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>--%>

            <div class="widget">
                <div class="widget-header">
                        <div class="title">
                            Received Complaints Via Sms&nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <!-- widget title-->
                </div> <!-- widget header -->

                        <div class="widget-body">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
      <!-- cons start -->
           <div class="shortcut-group">
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldSetMessage" runat="server" 
                 ClientIDMode="Static"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldShowMessage" runat="server" 
                 ClientIDMode="Static"/>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldIsValidDropDownValue" runat="server" 
                 ClientIDMode="Static" />


        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updGridViewSMS" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <ContentTemplate>
            <label><b>Search By Date Range</b></label>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateFrom" runat="server" Text="From"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>                      
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderFromDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtFromDate" runat="server">
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtFromDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ForeColor="Red" >
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDateTo" runat="server" Text="To"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtenderToDate" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtToDate" runat="server">
            </asp:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator10" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtToDate" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ForeColor="Red" >
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSearchByDate"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Search" 
                        ClientIDMode="Static"  OnClick="btnSearchByDate_Click" />
            <asp:ValidationSummary
             HeaderText="Requires Date Range:"
             DisplayMode="SingleParagraph"
             EnableClientScript="true"
             ForeColor="Red"
             runat="server" ID="ValidationSummary1"/>
           <label runat="server" id="lblSelectionMessage" style="color:navy; font-size:12px; font-style:italic" visible="false">
               Please select one validity dropdown at a time
           </label>
           <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSmsComplaints" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" BorderColor="#333333"  Width="650px" OnRowDataBound="GridViewSmsComplaints_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridViewSmsComplaints_PageIndexChanging" >
               <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sms ID" DataField="ID" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Recieving Date" DataField="RecievingDate" />  
                    <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ToMobileNo" DataField="ToMobileNo" />  --%>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Complainant Mob No." DataField="FromMobileNo" /> 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Complaint" DataField="Message" >   
                     <ItemStyle Wrap="True" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Complete/InComplete">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                       <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="ckboxIsComplaint"  runat="server" />--%>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsComplaint" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlIsComplaint_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="InComplete" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Complete" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                       </asp:DropDownList>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
               </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>    

        <br />
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlBoxesDropDowns" runat="server">
        <label>Complainant</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComplainant" runat="server" CssClass="textField_width"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValdiatorComplainant" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtComplainant" ErrorMessage="Complainant is Required" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Complainant is Required
        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <label style="width:400px">Relevant Region</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRegions" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" Width="147px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRegions_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True"  AutoPostBack="true" >
          <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Selected="True">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorRegions" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="ddlRegions" ErrorMessage="Region is Required" InitialValue="-1"
         ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Region is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <label style="width:400px">Relevant District</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDistricts" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown_Width" Width="147px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDistricts_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorDistricts" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="ddlDistricts" ErrorMessage="Region is Required" InitialValue="-1"
         ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Complaints">District is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <label>Relevant P.Station</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPoliceStations" runat="server" Width="147px" CssClass="DropDown_Width">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ReqFieldValidatorPoliceStations" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="ddlPoliceStations" ErrorMessage="Police Station is Required" InitialValue="-1"
         ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="Complaints">Police Station is Required</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <label>Priority</label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPriority" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="Top" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Normal" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <br />
            <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="60000" ID="RefreshSmsComplaints" OnTick="RefreshSmsComplaints_Tick" />
          </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RefreshSmsComplaints" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSendSms" ValidationGroup="Complaints"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success"  
            OnClick="btnSendSms_Click" Text="Send Sms" />
        <%--<asp:Button ID="btnGenerateReport"  CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" Text="Generate Report" 
                        ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnGenerateReport_Click" />--%>
        <br />
        <br />
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="550px">
                    <LocalReport ReportPath="Reports\GetReceivedComplaintsReport.rdlc">
                    </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>


    <br />
    <br />
                            &nbsp



                                     </div> <!-- shourtcut group">
                        <!-- cons end -->

                                                </div> <!-- row fluid -->
                    </div> <!-- widget body-->

            </div> <!-- widget-->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <!-- Modal -->



</asp:Content>
```

even i used maintainscrollbackposition attribute in page directive and code but it doesn't work, i am using firefox. Even i used this code after scriptmanager tag but it works not perfectly like it maintain scroll back position of page but doesn't load values in drop down upon clicking.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xPos, yPos;
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        xPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft;
        yPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop;
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $get('scrollDiv').scrollLeft = xPos;
        $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134963/prevent-page-scrolling-after-postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134963/prevent-page-scrolling-after-postback)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use Focus() method on your first Dropdownlist selection,

Consider this is an example

**On Code Behind**

```
Protected void ddlstate_click(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
   ddlcity.Focus();
}
```

It will do the trick as you want.

Comment: This is just as an example. Have you tried with your controls?

Comment: Still the page is staying at top level ?

Comment: If am not wrong, you want to select the state from first drop down, based on selection you want to load the cities in second drop down. At the time you are facing difficulties with scrolling right ?. If so am sure this will work. On first drop down selection, place the above line.

Comment: So try to place the code in your question. I will try to guide from you there.

Comment: Remove all your scripts which are placed in your page as you mentioned in your question.